# CSS: Absolute Position and Z-index

Tags: html, css

Is `z-index` only used when you set an element's position to `absolute` or it can also be used with an element having position set to `relative`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the W3C specification:

> z-index only works on positioned
>   elements (position:absolute,
>   position:relative, or position:fixed).

source: http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_z-index.asp